# ObjectInputStream blocking in readObject()

Tags: java, serialization, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm writing a client/server application in which server sends serializable objects to client via ObjectOutputStream (i'll call it oos from now on) and client gets 'em with ObjectInputStream ("ois" from now on).

Now, since the server is executed first, I initialize the oos first. As it should be. Here's how I initialize it:

```
OutputStream outStream=incoming.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream outToClient=new DataOutputStream(outStream);
outToClient.flush();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);  
oos.flush();
```

Then I start the client and I initialize the ois with these line:

```
inStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
```

From now on, the server side will send many objects on the same stream this way:

```
oos.writeUnshared(wishes);
```

in a while loop.
The problem is: when I execute this goddamn code on my pc alone, it's all good. No problems at all. When I try on two different machines, deadlock appears. The client side remains hanging on this line forever:

```
tempWishes = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
```

Feel free to ask more details. I didn't share the whole client and server code because it's like 500 lines of code.

Comment: Are you sure what you saw is deadlock, not blocking, which points to a totally different problem? If this is indeed deadlock, what are the locks?

Comment: Sounds like a buffering problem. Make sure you flush() or close() `oos` after writing the objects at the server side.

Comment: Already using flush(). Thanks!

Comment: (1) This is not a deadlock. It is a block. (2) It isn't in ObjectOutputStream, it is in ObjectInputStream.readObject(). (3) You should get rid of the DataOutputStream. You don't need it. ObjectOutputStream has all those methods. And if you're using a DataInputStream, get rid of that too.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious:

```
DataOutputStream outToClient=new DataOutputStream(outStream);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
```

Both `outToClient` and `oos` are writing to the same underlying stream. This is likely to cause weirdness.

@EJP's suggestion that you remove the `DataOutputStream` is a good one because the `DataOutputStream` class isn't what you're after (since you're writing objects), and you almost certainly want a single chain of `OutputStream`s.

Comment: Since I only need to send objects in certain cases, I thought of using the DataOutputStream to send a message to the client saying: "what you will get next is a object" or "what you will get next is a string". In the second case I just keep using the DataOutputStream, while in the first one the Client starts waiting for an object with the line readObject() method. Now changed in readUnshared(). I guess this way of thinking was wrong.

Comment: `ObjectOutputStream` implements the `DataOutput` interface so you can use a single `ObjectOutputStream` for both roles.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ois.readUnshared() instead of ois.readObject(). Even though it may no be the whole issue, it may be some other, it's good practice to couple write and reads.

Let me know if this fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, this helped partially, as the problem was also extended to my Socket definition. Now, even more funny, my application works properly in debug mode but gives the same problem of my question during a plain run.

Comment: This won't fix it, and it's only a good practice if you want to deliberately break the object graph. That's why it isn't the default.